# Is there a deeper meaning behind Sati being Indian?

Tags: the-matrix

Is there a deeper meaning behind Sati being Indian?

Meaning, was it just their artistic choice, or was there some reference or sendoff to a **concept or idea from an Indian culture or philosophy or Hinduism** made by by Wachovskys?

Comment: This is something that has been debated literally since the third film hit cinemas. There are dozens of threads on as many boards throughout the internet, and no-one has ever worked out if there is any significance to the name. @Jaydee's description below is a theory I've seen before, and seems to be the most sensible and logical. Of course, this being the Wachowski brothers, that almost certainly makes it the wrong answer. I've even heard the theory that it was Lana/ Larry Wachowski pseudonym when cross-dressing, before his/ her sex-change operation. I don't think that theory holds up.

Comment: since her *parents* were Indian ;)

Comment: @JamesSheridan could you give a link selection for example of 'dozens' of threads? good for reference and as underpinning. ;)

Comment: @naxa: I didn't thinks links worked in comments? Regardless, a quick Google search (Sati Matrix Indian) nets me three different threads, one of them 40 pages long, as the first three results. For those who are interested, this thread doesn't appear until the third page on Google, despite being the most recently updated.

Comment: @JamesSheridan (meta) yes [comments work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37758/): `[name](http://url)`. along with *`*italics*`* **`**bold**`** and `\`code formatting\``

Comment: @JamesSheridan  google search is insufficient here why. **1.** google puts you in ['search bubble'](http://dontbubble.us/): your results differ from mine. google do personally profile us that differs. you may be US I may be Hungary (I am), another diff. [Longest thread](http://forums.comingsoon.net/showthread.php?t=20265) I found from first 3 resultpage is 17 forum pages, seems like mismatch. **2.** I do this close real-time, but 2 years from now each hit will be different and new readers won't know what were we talking about, cutting possibility to push conversation further.

Comment: Sometimes an Indian is just an Indian.

Answer (score 4):

If it references anything I can only think it may be a reference to the Buddhist "Sati"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sati_%28Buddhism%29

> The word sati derives from a root meaning 'to remember,' but as a
>   mental factor it signifies presence of mind, attentiveness to the
>   present, rather than the faculty of memory regarding the past.

http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Sati

Comment: How and why does that concept tie in with The Matrix?

Comment: It is one of the "Seven Factors of Enlightenment". Enlightenment being one reading of certain aspects of the matrix, Neo's awakening for example.

Answer (score 1):

There are many references to Hinduism, Buddhism and Indian culture in The Matrix.  Take, for example, the shape of the lotus flower when Neo's body is taken by the machines.

Also the concept of Karma which is spoken by Sati's father to Neo in order to explain that concepts exist in all kinds of reality.  Real or virtual.

The name Sati also means "awareness" in buddhist circles.  The character of Sati appears to be a reference to this awareness.  So it makes sense that Sati's character would be Indian.